# Кодировка при отправке данных

Tags: кодировка, php, mysql

Есть небольшой код, который реализует отправку данных `ajax`

js

```
var message = $("#status_form").val();
    var username = "{usertitle}";
    ShowLoading('');
    $.post(dle_root + "engine/ajax/status.php", { text:message, user:username }, function(data){
        $("#mesto").html(data);
        $("#status_form").val('');
        HideLoading('');
    });
```

php

```
 <?php
@session_start();
@error_reporting ( E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE );
@ini_set ( 'display_errors', true );
@ini_set ( 'html_errors', false );
@ini_set ( 'error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE );

define( 'DATALIFEENGINE', true );
define( 'ROOT_DIR', substr( dirname(  __FILE__ ), 0, -12 ) );
define( 'ENGINE_DIR', ROOT_DIR . '/engine' );

require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/classes/mysql.php';
require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/data/dbconfig.php';

$db->super_query( "UPDATE " . USERPREFIX . "_users set u_status='$_POST[text]' where name='$_POST[user]'" );

if($_POST['text'] == "")$_POST['text']="Статуса нет.";

echo $_POST['text'];
?>
```

Так вот, в базу записываются непонятные иероглифы. Что делать?

Comment: Наверное всё же принудительно назначить скрипту и базе одну кодировку.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, для начала, думаю, неплохо было бы "енкодить" то, что посылаете на сервер. Прямо из JS. Это делает функция:

```
  encodeURIComponent(url);
```

Она никогда не будет лишней - вдруг пользователь ввел данные, содержащие "не url`овские" символы. В таком случае поведение может быть непредсказуемым...
Куда и как её подставлять, думаю, вы в состоянии сами понять. Тут особого интеллекта не нужно =)

Далее. Вы, как я вижу, работаете с MySQL через класс:

```
  $db->super_query();
```

Это правильно. Но так как я не вижу, что в классе, то не могу быть уверенным в том, что вы используете перед каким-л. модифицирующим набор данных запросом такой вот запрос, устанавливающий кодировку:

```
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
```

Comment: решил вопрос прописав 
$_POST['text'] = convert_unicode( $_POST['text'], $config['charset']  );
двиг Dle

Comment: Насколько мне известно, **convert_unicode()** - это штуковина из PHP 5.3.х...

Answer (score 0):

в php есть функция [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)(кодировка1, кодировка2, строка). преобразует строку из кодировки 1 в кодировку 2. Как вариант, перед добавлением в базу можно изменить кодировку.

Или [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-set-charset.php)